# DataBinding DropDownList inside GridView EditItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview which populates data witht a Dataset.
I also have a DropDownlist which is a an `EditTemplate` of a `TemplateField`.
I want to bind it to the dataset so that it can populate data from it.I searched it but it doesn't seem to work.I'm new to this. If not the code,Some help me to get hands on a good tutorial.

Heres my code snippet:

`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false) {
        BindGrid();

    }
}
private void BindGrid() { 
    //Get dataset
    //bind

    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Employees");
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Password=admin;User ID=admin;Initial Catalog=asptest;Data Source=dbsvr");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from employees", con);

    da.Fill(ds);
    gvEmp.DataSource = ds;
    gvEmp.DataBind();    
}


protected void gvEmp_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvEmp.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindGrid();
    BindDropDown();        
}

private void BindDropDown() {
    //DataSet ds = new DataSet("Employees");
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Password=priyal;User ID=priyal;Initial Catalog=asptest;Data Source=dbsvr");
    //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select deptno from employees", con);

    //da.Fill(ds);
    //gvEmp.DataSource = ds;
    //gvEmp.FindControl("ddlDept").DataBind();




}
protected void gvEmp_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    //this means that no index is selected
    gvEmp.EditIndex = -1;
}`
```

The commented code is what I tried.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
protected void gvEmp_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    DemoGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindGrid();
    DropDownList dropdown = gvEmp.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
    BindDropDown(dropdown);
}

private void BindDropDown(DropDownList temp)
{
    string connectionString = "Password=priyal;User ID=priyal;Initial Catalog=asptest;Data Source=dbsvr";
    string query = "select deptno from employees";
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet("Employees");
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
        {
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
        }
    }

    temp.DataSource = dataset;
    temp.DataTextField = "deptno";
    temp.DataValueField = "deptno";
    temp.DataBind();
}
```

Unless you pass the rows `DropDownList` as a parameter, how would your `BindDropDown` recognize which `DropDownList` to bind to?

Comment: I think gvEmp.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Columms[columnIndex] will do the trick

Comment: as he said he have a dropdownlist inside edititemtemplate its always better to access it by id for the sake of readability and maintainability.

Comment: I think this is what I would need for my issue. Would you be kind enough to shed some light on my question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394054/how-to-update-the-dropdownlist-based-on-the-filtered-gridview Thanks

Comment: And also this one please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436296/how-to-make-dropdownlist-dynamic-from-filtered-gridview

Answer (score 1):

I think you were close - try this in the BindDropDown() method:

```
// Set the DropDownList's DataSource (originally you were setting the GridView's DataSource
((DropDownList)gvEmp.FindControl("ddlDept")).DataSource = ds;
// Call DataBind() on the DropDownList
((DropDownList)gvEmp.FindControl("ddlDept")).DataBind();
```

You need to locate the control in the GridView, cast it to the correct type of control (in this case, DropDownList) and then perform actions on it.

Comment: Cating it is not helping. The code stops executing at.. `((DropDownList)gvEmp.FindControl("ddlDept")).DataSource = ds;`

Comment: FindControl() is not recursive as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx