# Populating a dropdownlist in the rowEditing event of a GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView as below

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvChain" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <headerstyle backcolor="#CCCCCC" />
  <columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" />
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manager Level 1">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblManager1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="cbManager1" runat="server"/>
    </EditItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manager Level 2">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblManager2" runat="server"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="cbManager2" runat="server"/>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True">
      <ControlStyle ForeColor="#009EDD" />
    </asp:CommandField>
  </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The BoundField 'Department' is being populated in the Page_Load as below which works fine and populates the GridView with a list of departments.

```
Dim dhandler As DepartmentHandler = New DepartmentHandler
Dim depts As New List(Of Department)

depts = dhandler.GetDepartmentList

gvChain.DataSource = depts
gvChain.DataBind()
```

I am then populating the ItemTemplates of the TemplateFields in the RowDAtaBound event as below. this is also working fine.

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
  Dim lblManager1 As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblManager1"), Label)
  Dim lblManager2 As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblManager2"), Label)

  Dim eHandler As EmployeeHandler = New EmployeeHandler
  Dim deptCell As TableCell = e.Row.Cells(0)
  Dim dept As Department = New Department
  dept.Department = deptCell.Text
  Dim mgr1 As Manager = eHandler.getManager1(dept)
  Dim mgr2 As Manager = eHandler.getManager2(dept)

  lblManager1.Text = mgr1.Name
  lblManager2.Text = mgr2.Name
End If
```

What I now want to achieve is when clicking on the 'Edit' field of a row on the GridView, populate cbManager1 and cbManager2 with a list of Managers and set the SelectedValue of each DDL to the same values as I am retrieving in the item template. I can get the data with the below code in the RowEditing event of the GridView:

```
' Get the list of managers
Dim mgrs As New List(Of Manager)
mgrs = eHandler.GetManagerList

' Get the department name from the BoundField
Dim deptCell As TableCell = gvChain.Rows(e.NewEditIndex).Cells(0)
Dim dept As Department = New Department
dept.Department = deptCell.Text

' Pass the department name to the getManager1/2 functions to return the correct manager for that department
Dim mgr1 As Manager = eHandler.getManager1(dept)
Dim mgr2 As Manager = eHandler.getManager2(dept)
```

I have set breakpoints to check the data is being returned from the functions and the data is there as expected but where I am stuck is getting a reference on the DDLs in the EditItemTemplate so I can databind them and set the SelectedValue.

I have tried the below but this is giving a NullReference Exception:

```
Dim cbManager1 As DropDownList = TryCast(gvChain.Rows(e.NewEditIndex).FindControl("cbManager1"), DropDownList)
Dim cbManager2 As DropDownList = TryCast(gvChain.Rows(e.NewEditIndex).FindControl("cbManager2"), DropDownList)
```

Comment: Where you are trying the last two statement I mean in which event?

Comment: Sorry, they are in the RowEditing event

Comment: @Jimsan - You should check this: [DataBinding DropDownList inside GridView EditItemTemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6922403/690329).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got round this in the end. I added the following code to the RowEditing event

```
gvChain.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
gvChain.DataBind()
```

I then did the following in the RowDataBound event

```
If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit Then
  Dim cbManager1 As DropDownList = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("cbManager1"), DropDownList)
  Dim cbManager2 As DropDownList = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("cbManager2"), DropDownList)

  Dim eHandler As EmployeeHandler = New EmployeeHandler

  Dim mgrs As New List(Of Manager)
  mgrs = eHandler.GetManagerList
  cbManager1.DataSource = mgrs
  cbManager2.DataSource = mgrs
  cbManager1.DataValueField = "Name"
  cbManager1.DataTextField = "Name"
  cbManager2.DataValueField = "Name"
  cbManager2.DataValueField = "Name"
  cbManager1.DataBind()
  cbManager2.DataBind()

  ' Got rid of the bound field in the end and did it with a templatefield so needed to get the department from the label
  Dim lbl As Label = e.Row.Cells(0).FindControl("lblDepartment")
  Dim dept As Department = New Department
  dept.Department = lbl.Text

  Dim mgr1 As Manager = eHandler.getManager1(dept)
  Dim mgr2 As Manager = eHandler.getManager2(dept)

  Dim mgr1Name As String = mgr1.Name.ToUpper()
  Dim mgr2Name As String = mgr2.Name.ToUpper()

  cbManager1.SelectedValue = mgr1Name
  cbManager2.SelectedValue = mgr2Name
End If
```

Comment: If the row being edited is an Alternate (even numbered) row, then the RowState is an "or" of .Alternate and .Edit .  I had to change my If statement to this (in VB):
    If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit Or e.Row.RowState = (DataControlRowState.Alternate Or DataControlRowState.Edit) Then

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit Then    
   Dim cbmanager As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("cbmanager1")    
   If Not cbmanager Is Nothing Then cbmanager.Items.Add(New ListItem("Test1", "Test1"))       
End If
```

Comment: This won't work in the RowEditing event. I have been doing some more research and it seems I'm barking up the wrong tree. RowEditing event occurs on clicking the edit button but before the GridView goes into edit mode. As my DDLs are in the EditItemTemplate they don't exist yet when trying to reference them in the RowEditing event. I need a different approach altogether. I  think I need to get my GridView into edit mode than proceed as you suggest in the RowDataBound event