# How to update the DropDownList based on the filtered GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, filtering

I have the following code which is a `GridView` and right above it I have `DropDownList` which allows me to filter:

```
<table class="taskGridView">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaskName" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateTaskName" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Task Name" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTaskName_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateTaskName" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ATTR2739] 'Task Name' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON CT.ATTR2846 = S.ATTR2821 INNER JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON S.FK2852 = (UA.USERNUM * -1) WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 20%;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlService" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateService" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Service" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlService_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateService" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ATTR2846] 'Service' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON CT.ATTR2846 = S.ATTR2821 INNER JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON S.FK2852 = (UA.USERNUM * -1) WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 11%;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateStatus" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Status" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateStatus" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ATTR2812] 'Status' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON CT.ATTR2846 = S.ATTR2821 INNER JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON S.FK2852 = (UA.USERNUM * -1) WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 14%;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDueDate" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateDueDate" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Due Date" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDueDate_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateDueDate" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(14), [ATTR2752], 110) 'Due Date' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON CT.ATTR2846 = S.ATTR2821 INNER JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON S.FK2852 = (UA.USERNUM * -1) WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOwner" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateOwner" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Owner" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOwner_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateOwner" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [REALNAME] 'Owner' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON CT.ATTR2846 = S.ATTR2821 INNER JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON S.FK2852 = (UA.USERNUM * -1) WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" CssClass="chosen-select" DataSourceID="dsPopulateClient" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Client" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClient_onSelectIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateClient" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gvConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ATTR2799] 'Client' FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT INNER JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON CT.ATTR2846 = S.ATTR2821 INNER JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON S.FK2852 = (UA.USERNUM * -1) WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="There is no data to display" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="yourTasksGV_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Detail" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Service" HeaderText="Service" SortExpression="Service" ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due Date" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="Owner" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Client" HeaderText="Client" SortExpression="Client" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code which allows me to populate and filter the table:

```
public void PullData(string sortExp, string sortDir)
{
    string query = "";
    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    connString = @""; //my connection string
    if (ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2739 = '" + ddlTaskName.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
    }
    else
    {
        strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2739 LIKE '%'";
    }
    if (ddlService.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2846 = '" + ddlService.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
    }
    else
    {
        strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2846 LIKE '%'";
    }
    if (ddlStatus.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2812 = '" + ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
    }
    else
    {
        strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2812 LIKE '%'";
    }
    if (ddlDueDate.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        strClause += " AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(14), CT.ATTR2752, 110) = '" + ddlDueDate.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
    }
    else
    {
        strClause += " AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(14), CT.ATTR2752, 110) LIKE '%'";
    }
    if (ddlOwner.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        strClause += " AND UA.REALNAME = '" + ddlOwner.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
    }
    else
    {
        strClause += " AND UA.REALNAME LIKE '%'";
    }
    if (ddlClient.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2799 = '" + ddlClient.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
    }
    else
    {
        strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2799 LIKE '%'";
    }

    if (ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlService.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlStatus.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlDueDate.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlOwner.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlClient.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0";
    }
    else
    {
        query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0" + strClause;
    }

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            DataView myDataView = new DataView();
            myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            if (sortExp != string.Empty)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(sortExp);
                //MessageBox.Show(sortDir);
                myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", sortExp, sortDir);
            }

            yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

            TasksUpdatePanel.Update();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
protected void ddlTaskName_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PullData(ViewState["sortExp"].ToString(), ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString());
}
protected void ddlOwner_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PullData(ViewState["sortExp"].ToString(), ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString());
}
protected void ddlService_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PullData(ViewState["sortExp"].ToString(), ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString());
}
protected void ddlStatus_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PullData(ViewState["sortExp"].ToString(), ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString());
}
protected void ddlDueDate_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PullData(ViewState["sortExp"].ToString(), ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString());
}
protected void ddlClient_onSelectIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PullData(ViewState["sortExp"].ToString(), ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString());
}

public string sortOrder
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString() == "Desc")
        {
            ViewState["sortOrder"] = "Asc";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["sortOrder"] = "Desc";
        }

        return ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["sortOrder"] = value;
    }
}
```

Now what is happening is when the page is loaded, the `GridView` is populated and also the `DropDownList` is populated. When I filter the `GridView` from one of the `DropDownList`, how do I modify my ASP.net page or code behind so the rest of the `DropDownList` is changed based on the filtered `GridView`?

Right now the `DropDownList` is hard coded, but I would like it to be dynamic so the `DropDownList` shows the data from the updated `GridView`.

UPDATE: I updated the `PullData` function to this:

```
public void PullData(string sortExp, string sortDir)
        {
            string query = "";
            DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
            connString = @""; //connection string
            if (ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2739 = '" + ddlTaskName.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2739 LIKE '%'";
            }
            if (ddlService.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2846 = '" + ddlService.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2846 LIKE '%'";
            }
            if (ddlStatus.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2812 = '" + ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                strClause += " AND CT.ATTR2812 LIKE '%'";
            }
            if (ddlDueDate.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                strClause += " AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(14), CT.ATTR2752, 110) = '" + ddlDueDate.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                strClause += " AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(14), CT.ATTR2752, 110) LIKE '%'";
            }
            if (ddlOwner.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                strClause += " AND UA.REALNAME = '" + ddlOwner.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                strClause += " AND UA.REALNAME LIKE '%'";
            }
            if (ddlClient.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                strClause += " AND C.ATTR2815 = '" + ddlClient.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                strClause += " AND C.ATTR2815 LIKE '%'";
            }
            if (ddlSite.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                strClause += " AND SI.ATTR2819 = '" + ddlSite.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                strClause += " AND SI.ATTR2819 LIKE '%'";
            }
            if (ddlPractice.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                strClause += " AND PR.ATTR2817 = '" + ddlPractice.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                strClause += " AND PR.ATTR2817 LIKE '%'";
            }
            if (ddlProvider.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                strClause += " AND P.ATTR2919 = '" + ddlProvider.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                strClause += " AND P.ATTR2919 LIKE '%'";
            }


            if (ddlTaskName.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlService.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlStatus.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlDueDate.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlOwner.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlClient.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlSite.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlPractice.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlProvider.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0";
            }
            else
            {
                query = strMainQuery + " WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0" + strClause;
            }

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                    // create data adapter
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                    // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

                    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(myDataSet);

                    myDataView = new DataView();
                    myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

                    if (sortExp != string.Empty)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show(sortExp);
                        //MessageBox.Show(sortDir);
                        myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", sortExp, sortDir);
                    }

                    yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
                    yourTasksGV.DataBind();

                    DataTable dt = myDataView.ToTable(true, "Task Name");
                    var rows = (from DataRow dRow in dt.Rows select new { Name = dRow["Task Name"], ID = dRow["Task Detail"] }).Distinct();
                    ddlTaskName.DataSource = rows;
                    ddlTaskName.DataTextField = "Task Name";
                    ddlTaskName.DataValueField = "Task Detail";
                    ddlTaskName.DataBind();

                    TasksUpdatePanel.Update();

                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string error = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
```

It is failing with this error:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'ddlTaskName'.  Remove one definition.
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.EnsureSingleDataSource()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.ConnectToDataSourceView()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.GetData()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
   at OB.Pages.YT.PullData(String sortExp, String sortDir) in Tasks.aspx.cs:line 210}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question what i understand is you want to associate every dropdown with respective columns of gridview.if i am right you can do this

```
    ddlTaskName.DataSource = myDataView;
    ddlTaskName.DataTextField = "Name";//Name of column which you want to display as text
    ddlTaskName.DataValueField = "ID";//Name of column which you want to be Value of dropdown list items.
    ddlTaskName.DataBind();
```

You will have to do this for every dropdown in your PullData method.

Update 1

Here are two methods you can try if your DataValueFiled and DataTextFeild are same than you can try this

```
    DataTable dt = myDataView.ToTable(true, "Name");
    ddlTaskName.DataSource = dt;
    ddlTaskName.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlTaskName.DataValueField = "Name";
    ddlTaskName.DataBind();
```

This will only select one column and that is Name column. If you have different DataValueField and DataTextFeild than you can try this

```
var rows = (from DataRow dRow in dt.Rows select new { Name = dRow["Name"], ID = dRow["ID"] }).Distinct();
 ddlTaskName.DataSource = rows;
    ddlTaskName.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlTaskName.DataValueField = "ID";
    ddlTaskName.DataBind();
```

===========================Update 2===============

Ok Here you go

Now your first drop down will look like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaskName" CssClass="chosen-select" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTaskName_onSelectIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Now on page load you will fill this with data what ever you want like this

```
    ddlTaskName.DataSource = "your dataset ot datatable or dataview name";
    ddlTaskName.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlTaskName.DataValueField = "ID";
    ddlTaskName.DataBind();
```

And in Pull data method you will do like this

```
 var rows = (from DataRow dRow in dt.Rows select new { Name = dRow["Name"], ID = dRow["ID"] }).Distinct();
    ddlTaskName.DataSource = rows;
    ddlTaskName.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlTaskName.DataValueField = "ID";
    ddlTaskName.DataBind();
```

The dt here is DataTable object if you are filling a dataset you can use like this myDataSet.Tables[0] instead of dt.

And to add an option "All" you can do like this

```
ddlTest.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All"));
```

This will insert "All" at the top you can change its location.

Comment: Thank you. I figured that would be something like that, But I need to have the `DropDownList` to have DISTINCT like it is in the ASP.net page code. Any way to do that?

Comment: Let's say the GridView has an entry of "FIX THIS" 20 times but the DropDownList should have only one "FIX THIS" as an entry. Will your code do that? Or if the GridView has 20 rows of "FIX THIS", it will show 20 times in the DropDownList?

Comment: Wow I didn't even see the update. Thank YOU... I will test it out! Where is the `dt` coming from?I am confused by the two piece of code. Only the first column displays the `NAME` which the link is for `ID` every other column the ValueField and TextField are the same

Comment: I updated my question with the new `PullData` function and the error I am receiving. Please keep in mind, I call `PullData` on page load to populate the `GridView` and then call it each time for sorting and changing the `DropDownList`.

Comment: You are getting this error because you have defined DataSourceID="dsPopulateTaskName" and you are also binding dropdown from code behind so you need to remove one i would say if you want to have distinct values in drop down than remove DataSourceID="dsPopulateTaskName" from drop down and bind from code behind(the code i provided you).You will have to do this for every drop down in which you want to have distinct values.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Can you please put them together for the first DropDownList in one section for me so I can replicate for the rest of the DropDownList? How do I also add the `All` option for all of them regardless of which DropDownList was selected?